# [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to update link training

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, dell

I just bought Dell Optiple 3050 with Ubuntu 16.04 prelaoded.
I installed Lubuntu 16.04.
Installation finished successfully with following message

[drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to update link training

No application launcher after enter into Lubuntu, only plain desktop.
Please help me to solve the problem.